# {{var payment_html}} is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, transactional-mail

In sales transactional e-mails I cannot find out how to make magento print **payment method.** I have two options (cash on delivery or credit card on delivery) for customers. It's empty every time.

In back-end at the View order page I can't see it neither because there is only written Order was placed using.

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875784/editing-magento-sales-e-mail-payment-block/14718022#14718022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found why var payment_html is totally empty but yet I found solution.

In transactional emails template use instead of `{{var payment_html}}` this

```
{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}
```

Now I see at least in those emails which method customers chose.